# Converse to a proposition on subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$. I read somewhere that if either $H$ or $K$ is a normal subgroup, then $HK$, which is the set of products from $H$ and $K$, is itself a subgroup. Is the converse true? That is, given that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$, must at least one of $H$ and $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Where did you read this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the converse is not true.

In general, if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups, then $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK=KH$ as sets; that is, for each $h\in H$ and $k\in K$, there exist $h’,h’’\in H$ and $k’,k’’\in K$ such that $hk=k’h’$ and $kh=h’’k’’$. (I’ll leave it to you to prove this; it’s a good exercise). If, say, $H$ is normal, then $kH=Hk$ for each $k\in K$ (in fact, for each $g\in G$), and so the condition will be met. However, it is possible for neither $H$ nor $K$ to be normal, and yet for the product to be a subgroup anyway.

An example of this take the dihedral group of order $8$, with $r$ a rotation and $s$ a reflection. Let $H=\{e,rs\}$ and $K=\{e,r^3s\}$. Neither is normal; e.g., $s(rs)s = sr = r^3s\notin H$; and $s(r^3s)s = sr^3 = rs\notin K$.

However, $HK= \{e, rs, r^3s, r^2\}$ and $KH=\{e,r^3s,rs, r^2\}=HK$, a subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

The product of two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a group $G$ is itself a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $HK = KH$.